# Is there any other solution to connect to iTunes after an iOS upgrade?

Tags: itunes

I have just downloaded the latest IOS upgrade on my iPhone, it is showing the connect to iTunes message, I no longer have a lap top, is there any other way to get my iPhone up and working again. Can it be connected to iPad ?

Comment: Try holding the Home and Power buttons until the Apple Logo appears.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, there's no other way, the phone us un-able to boot its Operating System, and as a result is falling back onto the plug into iTunes, take it to an Apple store, they are the nicest people ever, and will fix the issue, and tell you what caused it, and how to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the normal procedure for upgrading iOS. That would only happen if the update failed, and the OS on your phone is no longer functional.

If you don't have a computer, the only other option would be to take it to an Apple Store, or borrow a computer from someone else. (Even then, it is possible that it could be unrestorable.)